# when clicking an item on the taskbar it is always selected no aero peek

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, aero-peek

I have a problem the result is aero peek is not working , but it is enabled the problem is when I click any item in the taskbar it is always selected so when I hover no aero peek because it is selected ,I uploaded a video that demonstrate the problem

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJRBY0Tu4Po

I have tried to use registry cleaner programs but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

It might just be your video card is not enough to handle Aero. If you're video card is lesser than the requirements, even if you enable Aero, it won't work. At the bottom of this page has requirements to use Aero, check if yours is within reach for Aero to function.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-the-Aero-desktop-experience

Comment: please see the video the hardware is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

To find out if your computer can handle Aero, a good starting point is to run the [Microsoft Aero repair utility](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/aero_effects_not_working/en-us). It will tell you if there is a physical thing stopping it from working and if there is a problem that it can repair, it will.

Comment: i used it and no luck it says everything is fine

Comment: Try changing back your taskbar back to the default settings just to see if that still has the same affect.